# Creating ZIP on the fly produces corrupted file

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I'm trying to make some sort of download service for a school project. Concept is simple - create a zip file from uploaded files. First problem is asp.net on school server is configured that apps cannot write any files, so I'm storing them in database. Then I need to create zip from these. Again, no writing on disk. I managed to get it to work. Almost - the code produces corrupted file.

<s>Fun fact is that commented part produces working file. The difference is in 11th and 12th byte. It seems to be checksum or file length, but in corrupted file it is different each time.</s>

The solution to this problem is using DotNetZip lib, but I think it is a matter of one line or something, because there are only 2 bytes wrong. (Bytes 12-15 correspond to modification date and time, so they had to be different. I'm not sure why my editor didn't show me that there's chunk of data missing at the end).

Corrupted file is missing a signature at the end. It may be caused by wrong content length header or zip generation.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // var filepath = context.Server.MapPath("files\\") + Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip";
    // var zip = ZipFile.Open(filepath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    var mzip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //zip.CreateEntryFromFile((string) reader["path"], (string) reader["name"], CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        var contents = (byte[]) reader["contents"];
        var stream = mzip.CreateEntry((string) reader["name"], CompressionLevel.Optimal).Open();
        using (var fs = new MemoryStream(contents))
        {
            fs.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
    //  zip.Dispose();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/ocetet-stream";
    Response.HeaderEncoding = Response.ContentEncoding;

    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + gname + ".zip\"");
    //Response.AppendHeader("content-length", new FileInfo(filepath).Length.ToString());
    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", memoryStream.Length.ToString());

    // Response.TransmitFile(filepath);
    Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Also - I'm new to C#, so my code may be pretty bad.

Comment: not sure but wont the ziparchive be created with an empty `Stream`?

Comment: do you mean it can be created with `Stream` instead of `MemoryStream` or it produces just empty stream?